# Does playing the arrival DLC have any effect in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Are there any choices made in the arrival DLC that influence ME3?

I am anxious to play ME3 but am considering playing Arrival first, but only if it will further influence things in ME3.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Without any spoilers, the reason is that the Arrival acts as a story bridge to ME3, but does not present any major choices; everything that happens *has* to happen, or else you just lose (die).

Source - Experience

Answer (score 0):

Well, Anderson does mention what you did when asked why you were relieved of command. Beyond that there don't seem to be any consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You lose some EMS, and the end result is accomplished by a misc. squad instead of Shepard